# Complex Matrix Eigenvalue Bounds

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Problem Statement**: Generally, let $A$ be complex; then if

$$d_1 = \max\limits_{i, j} |a_{ij}|,\;\;\;d_2 = \max\limits_{i, j} |a_{ij} + \overline{a_{ji}}| / 2,\;\;\;\; d_3 = \max\limits_{i, j} |a_{ij} - \overline{a_{ji}}| / 2,$$

then we have

$$|\lambda|\leq Nd_1,\;\;\; |\text{Re }(\lambda)|\leq Nd_2,\;\;\; |\text{Im }(\lambda)|\leq Nd_3.$$

**My Attempt**: For the first inequality, we have for a normalized eigenvector $x$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ that

$$Ax = \lambda x \iff |Ax| = |\lambda x| \iff \left|\sum\limits_{j=1}^N A_{ij}x_j\right| = |\lambda| \iff |\lambda| \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^N |A_{ij}|\leq Nd_1.$$

For the second two, we have that

$$A = H + S = \frac{1}{2} (A + A^*) + \frac{1}{2} (A - A^*)$$

where $H$ is Hermitian and $S$ is skew-Hermitian. From here, we just show that for a complex eigenvalue $\lambda = a + bi$, we have that $Hx = ax$ and $Sx = (bi) x$, so that

$$Ax = (H + S) x = (a + bi) x = \lambda x.$$

This is evident as

$$Hx=\frac{1}{2} (A + A^*)x = \frac{1}{2} \lambda x + \frac{1}{2} \overline{\lambda} x = \text{Re } (\lambda) x$$

and

$$Sx=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^*)x=\frac{1}{2}\lambda x - \frac{1}{2} \overline{\lambda} x = \text{Im } (\lambda) x.$$

From here, we can use the first inequality to bound the real and complex parts of the eigenvalue which proves the latter two inequalities if we consider the matrices $H$ and $S$ instead of $A$.

**Question:** Does my work make sense - specifically the first inequality as the latter two hinge upon the first? I am also interested as to why we care/applications about the latter two inequalities - bounding the real and imaginary parts separately for complex matrices.

**Source**: Richard Bellman - "Introduction to Matrix Analysis"

Comment: For the last part: The spectral bound $s(A)$ of a matrix $A$ (more generally, an operator $A$), which is defined as $s(A):= \{\Re \lambda\mid \lambda\in\sigma(A)\}$ plays a very important role in the theory of dynamic systems, more specifically in operator semigroups and the investigation of their stability. There, we usually look at the asymptotic behaviour of $e^{At}$ with $t\to\infty$, $t\in [0,\infty)$. It turns out, that in many cases a sufficient condition for $e^{At}\to 0$ is $s(A)<0$, similar to how the absolute value of $e^\lambda$ is only determined by the real part of $\lambda$.